# Javascript not responsive on resize

Tags: javascript

Newbie to Javascript here.

I'm trying to make a simple one-page site with 3 sections: the Title area, a Portfolio area, and a contact form. Each of these sections is anchor-linked, so when the link is clicked the page scrolls down to that section.

I've used javascript to ensure that each section will fill the screen, centered horizontally and vertically if space permits. However, these measurements won't update on window resize.

I can't pinpoint the issue, since my initial code, which controls the height of the header depending on the height of the viewport, did update on resize until I added in the new lines.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
        function resize()
        {
            var heights = window.innerHeight;
            var header = document.getElementById('title').offsetHeight;
            var logo = document.getElementById('logo').offsetHeight;
            var portfolioHeight = document.getElementById('portfolio-buttons').offsetHeight;
            var hireHeight = document.getElementById('hire-form').offsetHeight;
            document.getElementById('header').style.height = heights - header - logo * 0.4 + "px";
            document.getElementById('portfolio').style.padding = (heights - portfolioHeight) * 0.5 + "px 0";
            document.getElementById('hire').style.padding = (heights - hireHeight) * 0.5 + 5 + "px 0";   
        }
        resize();
        window.onresize = function() {
            resize();
        };
        //]]>
</script>
```

And here is the basic structure of the relevant HTML :

```
<div id="portfolio">
    <div id="portfolio-buttons">
         Content here
    </div>
</div>
<div id="hire">
    <div id="hire-form">
         Content here
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: To be extra clear, here are the lines that work as their own script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
        function resize()
        {
            var heights = window.innerHeight;
            var header = document.getElementById('title').offsetHeight;
            var logo = document.getElementById('logo').offsetHeight;
            document.getElementById('header').style.height = heights - header - logo * 0.4 + "px";   
        }
        resize();
        window.onresize = function() {
            resize();
        };
        //]]>
</script>
```

And here are those that work, but only update on refresh, not resize.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
        function resize()
        {
            var heights = window.innerHeight;
            var portfolioHeight = document.getElementById('portfolio-buttons').offsetHeight;
            var hireHeight = document.getElementById('hire-form').offsetHeight;
            document.getElementById('portfolio').style.padding = (heights - portfolioHeight) * 0.5 + "px 0";
            document.getElementById('hire').style.padding = (heights - hireHeight) * 0.5 + 5 + "px 0";
        }
        resize();
        window.onresize = function() {
            resize();
        };
        //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What lines did you add that broke it?  Also, are there any errors in the console?  We need more info!

Comment: Instead of wrapping your function in an anonymous function have you tried doing window.onresize = resize ?

Comment: @SuperScript I'll edit my post to break out the lines that work from the ones that don't. Only thing in the console is `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

Comment: @argo49 I tried replacing `window.onresize = function()` with `window.onresize = resize` but that just broke that script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
window.onresize = function() {
            resize();
            return true;
        };
```

If that doesn't work, try using `window.addEventListener("resize",function(){...})` isntead. To support older versions of IE, you'll have to check `if(window.addEventListener){/*standards*/window.addEventListener("resize",function(){...})}else{/*IE only*/ window.attachEvent("onresize",function(){...}`

Comment: window.addEventListener("resize",function() did the trick! Is that specifically telling it to check for a resize while the other one wasn't?

Comment: window.onresize is part of a more archaic DOM level-1 functionality. It is still mostly supported (as far as I knew) for most event handlers. Apparently this is not one of them. It was replaced by this approach so that developers could register multiple listeners to an event, and to allow more well-defined behavior as to whether the "default" event functionality would execute (e.g. navigating when clicking a link). In the old method, if your function returns a truthy value, it means continue with the default action- but what if there are multiple functions? So they created event.preventDefault